# Why does BULK COLLECT give a bad bind variable compile error in Oracle Package PROC?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, temp-tables, bulk-collect

I am trying to take in 3 strings to represent a set of last names, first names, and middle names.

The incoming parameters would end up looking like this:

```
lastNames IN VARCHAR2 := NULL
'Smith/Brown/Green'
firstNames IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
'Joseph/Dan/Sam'
miNames IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
'c.//J.'
```

The goal would be to build a filter for dynamic SQL like this:

```
v_namesFilter VARCHAR(32767 BYTE);

v_namesFilter := ' AND (last_name = ''Smith'' AND middle_name = ''C'' AND first_name = ''Joseph'') OR (last_name = ''Brown'' AND first_name = ''Dan'') OR (last_name = ''Green'' AND middle_name = ''J.'' AND first_name = ''Sam'')
```

So far I have an incoming param like this:

```
lastNames IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
```

Then after

```
IS(
```

I have:

```
v_last_names_tab     LAST_NAMES_TAB;
```

LAST_NAMES_TAB is defined like this:

```
create or replace TYPE "LAST_NAMES_TAB" AS TABLE OF LAST_NAMES;
```

LAST_NAMES is defined like this:

```
create or replaceTYPE "LAST_NAMES" AS OBJECT(
  lastName VARCHAR2(32767)
);
```

After my BEGIN, I have:

```
-- split last names into table
SELECT LAST_NAMES( lastName )
BULK COLLECT INTO :v_last_names_tab
FROM   (
  SELECT trim( regexp_substr(lastNames, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL) )AS lastName
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY instr(lastNames, '/', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
);
```

I would think this would fill up a table called v_last_names_tab of TYPE LAST_NAMES_TAB and look like this:

```
lastName
--------
Smith
Brown
Green
```

But I get "Bad Bind variable ":v_last_names_tab" error message when I try to compile.

How can I format my incoming data like this so I can roll through it.

Comment: You don't need to use the colon (":") to indicate a bind variable in PL/SQL context.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all the extra types and objects and can do it all in PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_Names_Filter(
  i_lastNames  IN VARCHAR2,
  i_firstNames IN VARCHAR2,
  i_miNames    IN VARCHAR2,
  o_filter   OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
  p_ln SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := split_String( i_lastNames, '/' );
  p_fn SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := split_String( i_firstNames, '/' );
  p_mn SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := split_String( i_miNames, '/' );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_ln.COUNT LOOP
    o_filter := o_filter
                || ' AND ( last_name ' || CASE WHEN p_ln(i) IS NULL THEN 'IS NULL' ELSE '= ''' || p_ln(i) || '''' END
                || ' AND middle_name ' || CASE WHEN p_mn(i) IS NULL THEN 'IS NULL' ELSE '= ''' || p_mn(i) || '''' END
                || ' AND first_name ' || CASE WHEN p_fn(i) IS NULL THEN 'IS NULL' ELSE '= ''' || p_fn(i) || '''' END
                || ')';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
BULK COLLECT INTO :v_last_names_tab
```

By

```
BULK COLLECT INTO v_last_names_tab
```

Bind variables with leading `:` are not correct PL/SQL syntax.